GASプログラムを実行するとGoogleによって打ち切られ実行できない
某大学のICT部門に勤務しています。
学期始めに大学の履修データに基づきGoogle Classroomのコース作成とメンバー登録を行う必要があり、
Google Classroom APIを実行するGASプログラムを用いて対応してきました。
Google Workspace for EducationライセンスでのGASの実行上限時間は30分ですが、
授業の量が多いためスクリプトプロパティとトリガーを用いて30分を超えても自動継続する実装を行っておりました。
参考にしたサイト： https://qiita.com/s_maeda_fukui/items/d194c6408803229fe1b9
2024/7月に入ってから実行が途中で打ち切られる回数が増え、7/10を境に全く実行できなくなってしまいました。

以下試しましたがいずれも実行できず、Googleに悪意あるプログラムとして脅威認定されてしまったのではないかと考えています。

別のアカウントから実行
ソースコードを丸ごと移し替えた別のGASファイルで実行
ソースコード内容が微妙に異なる付属校向けのプログラムの実行

Googleに脅威認定を解除してもらう方法はありますでしょうか。
Google Workspaceサポートデスクに問い合わせましたが範囲外と言われ、Stack Overflowでの投稿を紹介されました。
何卒よろしくお願い致します。

おそらくサポートを受けたいなら英語版サイト Questions tagged [google-apps-script] の方に質問した方が良いのでは？ Apps Script のどこでサポートを受けられますか？にはApps Script については、Google Apps Script Community と Stack Overflow に大規模なオンライン コミュニティがあり、作業中の疑問点の解決に役立てていただけます。とありますがそのリンクは英語版サイトに飛んでいます。あるいは同じく書かれているようにGoogle Apps Script Communityか、その日本語版らしき Google Apps API Japan の方が助言とか得られ易いのでは？

ありがとうございます。英語版サイトにも質問をしてみました。

そもそも短時間(6分間、または、30分間)で終わらないような処理に、GASを使うという発想自体が間違っています。GASに実行時間の制限が設けられているのは、そのような長時間実行するような処理にGASを使うこと自体を想定していないからです。
あなたがすべきことは、今やっている処理をGASではない手段に移行することです。Google Classroom APIはGAS以外からでも使えます。手元のパソコンやサーバーからでもいいですし、従量課金のため実質制限がないGCF(Google Cloud Function)でもいいでしょう。いまあるGASのスクリプトはそのまま使えないかも知れませんが、制限回避のための変なコードを含まない分、シンプルになるはずです。
他の人もやっているかと言って、制限の回避を何も考えずに行わないでください。そのような方法は技術的保護手段の回避として規約違反に該当する可能性があります。スクリプトが強制的に無効にされても文句は言えません。あなたが書いたスクリプトがポリシーに違反している限り、有効になることはありません。

ご指摘ありがとうございます。
コロナ禍に伴う緊急対応として作成したプログラムをずっと使い続けてきてしまったのがそもそもの問題でした。
別の方法を検討致します。
